# My SQL code doesn't seem to be connecting to my server. It used to do it and it works on my Wamp server

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

This is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,email) VALUES('$username','$password','$email')";

$registerquery = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if($registerquery) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
}
```

It stops working as it gets to the `if($registerquery)` line.

It works on my WAMP server and it was working fine until recently but now all of a sudden it has stopped. Has anyone got any idea why this is happening?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php

Comment: You might also want to make sure you're not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and that you're properly hashing the password.

Comment: If it's not connecting, the problem is more likely at the `mysql_connect()` line, not at `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: can you connect to your database on the server? have you checked that?

Comment: This is more likely to be a server problem, not a PHP problem.

Comment: Well, given the code, `mysqli_query` could also be returning false because of query errors.  Since the code is wide open to SQL injection, you don't really know what SQL code you're actually executing.

Answer (score -1):

Check the SQL Connection (sql_connect) to your server.

If it works on your Wamp Server but not on your main server then it means that either of these have changed:

- Server Address
- Server Login Username
- Server Login Password
- Access to the database server over http (security change)

Rectifying either or all of these will solve the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for feedback. It is connecting to my server i have tested it with different $sql code and it works fine. This is why its confusing me.